# How to Fix Warp Stabilizer Incorrect Rotation

Tags: premiere, after-effects, stabilisation

I am using Warp Stabilizer on some footage and it's almost perfect but there's a random erroneous rotation in the middle.

Is there a way I can fix this manually, maybe go into the keyframes or correct some points?

**Edit:** or just disable rotation all together? (while keeping position and scaling)

[Here is an example clip](https://youtu.be/GZMKS7etJqc)

*(btw I lowered the frame-rate to make the stabilization faster)*

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

sorry I don't use this forum and have zero time to answer, but from the clip you posted I'd strongly suggest you don't use warp stabilizer - instead use "stabilize motion" and then make sure to check the "rotation" parameter so that you are given a second tracker - then once you've stabilized the position and rotation of the footage you'll have to do a little extra to manually slide the footage left or right depending on where the camera goes (look into stuff like "setting a null as the target for tracking motion" and you'll get a better understanding of all this stuff).